# UIImage not displaying properly on iPhone 5 Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm working with a collectionView Cell which only has UIImage. The image is pinned to the superview (in this case - all 4 sides of the cell).

The image looks great on iPhone 6,7, and plus devices. The image actually does not scale very well for iPhone 5. The UIImageView's contentMode is set to `.scaleAspectFill`. The image is being retrieved from the image assets.

I think iPhone 5 uses the 2x asset, but it might be too big that's why it doesn't display it properly. It looks like it's zoomed in and it crops the all 4 sides.

What is the work around this issue?

Comment: Try to make its size proportional and its content mode aspect fit

Comment: @Hosny all sides are pilled to their respective sides of the cell

Comment: And what about its content mode?

Comment: @Hosny is set to scaleAspectFit